# Mysql how to get column names of a sub-query?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have bellow query:

```
SELECT
    c.id AS 'course_id',u.id as 'user_id',c.round,u.first_name as name,u.last_name as family_name,u.`father_name`,u.`tazkera_id` as tazkira,c.`no` as class_ID,tc.province,tc.village,tl.id as training_provider_id,
    CASE c.`shift`
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Morning'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Afternoon'
    END as shift,
    c.`start_date`as start_date,
    sa.participant_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(ca.`date`,'%Y-%m-%d') as attendence,
    CASE sa.`precence` 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'A' 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'P' 
    END as attendence_status 
FROM `users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `provinces` as pu On pu.`province_code` = u.`province_code`
LEFT JOIN `districts` as du on du.`district_code` = u.`district_code`

LEFT JOIN `course_user` as cu ON cu.`user_id` = u.id AND cu.`relation_type` = 1
LEFT JOIN `courses` AS c On c.id = cu.`course_id`


LEFT JOIN `training_centers` as tc On tc.id = c.`training_center_id`
LEFT JOIN `training_providers` AS tl ON tl.id = tc.`training_provider_id`
/*** Training location **/
LEFT JOIN `provinces` as pt On pt.`province_code` = tc.`province`
LEFT JOIN `districts` as dt on dt.`district_code` = tc.`district`
LEFT JOIN `course_attendances` as ca ON ca.`course_id` = c.`id`
LEFT JOIN `student_attendances` as sa ON sa.`course_attendance_id` = ca.`id`

WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL AND sa.`participant_id` = u.id
GROUP BY sa.`participant_id`,ca.date order by u.id,ca.date
```

I want to take column names of above query with mysql.
Of course with php we can do that, but my question is, how to do that with mysql query? Is it possible ?

Comment: You're giving aliases to most of the things you select, so don't you already know the names of columns in the result set?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have many other queries like this, I use it is alias `src` as a table name in drodown, when user select it, i should run it's related query, and get all column names to show it in another drop down list for user.

Comment: Just some remarks to your query: Use double quotes for alias names; single quotes are for string literals. You join many tables that you don't use in your results (`provinces`, `districts`, both tables even twice, and the table `training_providers`, where you just use the `id` which you have with `training_centers.raining_provider_id` already). Why? You are also trying to outer join all tables. Is this on purpose? It doesn't seem to make sense and it doesn't even work, because you dismiss outer-joined records in your where clause. `WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL`? How can a table's ID be null?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You pointed most of my mistakes, thank u.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is merely the database system. You tell it what to select and it does so. In your case you tell it to select the `courses.id` and call it `course_id` and so on. The column names are implicit in the results. This works about like this: your app sends the query to MySQL; MySQL checks it and tells you whether it's okay. Your app asks for the columns; MySQL tells you column names and types. Your app asks for the rows; MySQL sends them.

Often you use an app that does all that automatically, say phpMyAdmin. And when writing such an app yourself, the language often hides all this from you (say the Java framework or .NET). But of course you can also ask for the column names and types explicitely, e.g. in PHP:

```
mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $column_index)
```

You will probably find much information on how to do this by simply searching for "MySQL" + <the language in question> + "column names".

Comment: Yeah, with languages like `PHP` we can do that, I have mentioned that. I have asked is it possible to do that with mysql or no ? thanks i will do it with `PHP`

Comment: MySQL is just the DBMS, just the machine. It's as if you wanted to watch an Internet Website on your computer and I tell you that you can use the Internet Explorer or Firefox or write a tool yourself, and you are asking: "yes, I know that Firefox can do it, but can the Internet do that also?".